# How to create a increment order drag down formula in excel like AT3, AU3, AV3,AW3,

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I simply want a formula for drag down increment order pattern like AS3,AT3...CZ3,DA3 for Microsoft Excel 2016

Comment: You should use INDEX or OFFSET - eg `'INDEX($AS$3:$DA$3,,ROWS($A$1:$A1))`

Answer (score 0):

How to do this is described in https://www.pryor.com/blog/create-a-custom-autofill-series-in-excel/

> Create your own AutoFill Series:
>
> - In a set of cells add the elements in your custom series in the right order.
> - Select the cells which contain the data you want to comprise your custom list.
> - Click the File tab.
> - Click the Excel Options button to open the Excel Options dialog box.
> - Click the Advanced button [A] and scroll to the bottom of the Advanced Options window.
> - Click the Edit Custom Lists button [B] to open the Custom Lists dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

```
=ADDRESS(3,ROW()+46-10,4)

3 = is the 3 you want to be displayed
46 = the start column number (you get it with this formula: =column()   )
-10 = the row number of your first cell with the desired value (AT3)
4 = skip the dollar sign
```

[image]